# Heuristic Consistency with float multiplications

Tags: search-algorithms, floating-point

I'm running A* search with a theoretically consistent heuristic.  I'm doing a lot of float multiplications, and I'm not sure how best to ensure that my heuristic remains consistent down to the last decimal point.  Is this something that is safe to ignore?

If it matters, my search objectives typically are around 5000, so maybe a small decimal inconsistency isn't relevant.  Curious what people typically do in this situation.  Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual calculation?

Comment: Replace "float" with "double" or "long double" or do a very careful analysis of your problem.